# 'C:\Users\jansen' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: react-native

why my react native app when i run "npx react-native run-android" keep showing error like this, i've checked my environtment path and cannot found any error
[image]

here is the environtment path
[image]

Comment: Hint: your home directory contains a space: "C:\Users\jansen stanlie". Bad interpreters create strings to execute processes rather than use proper path names. So on your side, you could use another directory to work from, without space. Asking to fix each and every NPM dependency would be a nightmare, so try to move your development environment from a name with spaces to a name without any spaces.

Comment: but how do i move to another directory when the path is only available in drive c...

Comment: is there any ways to fix the users folder name instead of moving into new directory..

Comment: I don't know, that's too "windowsy" for me. I only saw the issue, I can't provide a full solution (=answer) due to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: but u pretty sure it because of the whitespaces?, because i try to search the problem but didn't find any solution

Comment: I'm not "pretty sure": I'm certain that the whitespace in your folder name is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that the whitespaces not only impact the npm, but also when i create project on android studio